# how to filter with two condition in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to create an e-commerce website using react-bootstrap and for my product detail page I want to show the product based on the item chosen by the user which have different id and category. I want to filter so it only show the item that have the same id and category, but it didn't work it still show all of the item only based on their category. I want it to be based on category and id. How can I fix that ?

my Code:

```
const ProductList = () => {
  const { category, id } = useParams()
  const[productList, setProductList]= useState();

  useEffect(() =>{
    axios.get(`https://fakestoreapi.com/products`).then(res => {
        const products = res.data;
        var filteredCategory =
        products.filter((productList) =>
        productList.category === category || productList.id === id)
        setProductList(filteredCategory)
      })
  }, []);

  console.log()

  return (
    <>
      <Container fluid>
        
          {productList && productList.map(product =>{
            const {id, title, price, category,image} = product;
            return(
              <Row>
                <Col lg={3} className="d-flex">
                  <img src={image} width="50%"></img>
                </Col>

                <Col>
                  <h1> {title}</h1>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            )
          })}
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: In your code you have `products.filter((productList) => productList.category === category || productList.id === id)`. I guess you mean to use the `&&` operator in your, not `||`. Does that solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

product `id` from the API response is `number` type and `id` extracted from `useParams` is `string` type. You can ignore the type when comparing using `==` instead of `===`. And if you meant to filter with both conditions met then it should be `&&` instead of `||`.

Instead of

```js
productList.category === category || productList.id === id
```

Try

```js
productList.category === category && productList.id == id
```

[image: Edit zealous-lamarr-hyyb0e]

Comment: @Kim San, check this out !!